# Run "scrcpy" Commands And Throws Error "libopenh264.so.7 is missing" / "openh264 disabled"

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, fedora, openh264

I try to run `scrcpy` command like what I did before, and proved if it's worked not just once.

```
scrcpy -m 540 -S
```

but after re-installing my OS and use Fedora OS with dnf package manager, I got errors with output below.

```
WARN: Demuxer 'audio': stream explicitly disabled by the device
WARN: [FFmpeg] libopenh264.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory: libopenh264.so.7 is missing, openh264 support will be disabled
ERROR: Demuxer 'video': could not open codec
ERROR: Demuxer error
[server] INFO: Device screen turned off
```

Seems I got a problem here because `[FFmpeg] libopenh264.so.7` is missing and it cause `openh264` support disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying some commands that I found from Google, I found some articles with better relation to my problem.

https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?330574-nothing-provides-libopenh264-so-7()(64bit)-needed-by-libavcodec-freeworld-6-0-11-fc38&p=1871092

https://discussion.fedoraproject.org/t/dnf-update-fails-with-ffmpeg-libs/82595/3

And finally, after running the command below,

```
sudo dnf install openh264 mozilla-openh264
```

And then retrying to run the command below,

```
scrcpy -m 540 -S
```

My problem solved, and scrcpy worked like a charm.